# ¿como formular preguntas en prolog?

Tags: prolog

Me gustaría que me ayudaran a formular una pregunta en prolog y como relacionar las preguntas.

Por ejemplo:

- clara es madre de pedro
- pedro es padre de jose
- ana es madre de clara
- jose es padre de clara
- ¿es clara abuela de jose?
- ¿es pedro abuelo de clara?

Comment: porque has puesto como tag c# si la pregunta es solo prolog ?

Answer (score 4):

En este sentido el prolog es bastante sencillo. Primero defines las características básicas de padre, madre, etc... En tu caso:

Definimos qué es una madre y un padre:

```
mother(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y), female(X).
father(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y), male(X).
```

Definimos qué es abuelo y abuela:

```
grandfather(X,Y) :- parent(X,Z), parent(Z,Y), male(X)
grandmother(X,Y) :- parent(X,Z), parent(Z,Y), female(X)
```

¿Qué hemos hecho?

Vamos a analizar el predicado de `mother(X,Y)` :
Esto se analiza así: para saber si `X` es madre de `Y` hemos dicho que `X` tiene que ser `parent` de Y (su padre/madre) y `X` tiene que ser `female` (mujer)

Para finalizar tu ejemplo, definimos las relaciones expuestas en tu enunciado:

1. Definimos quién es hombre y mujer:

   ```
   male(pedro).
   male(jose).
   female(clara).
   female(ana).
   ```

   - Clara es madre de pedro

     `mother(clara, pedro).`
   - Pedro es padre de jose

     `father(pedro, jose).`
   - ana es madre de clara

     `mother(ana, clara).`
   - jose es padre de clara

     `mother(jose, clara).`

Cuándo ya lo tenemos todo definido, nos hacemos las preguntas, para hacerlo, utilizamos `? -` seguido de la pregunta:

- ¿es clara abuela de jose ?

  ```
  ? - grandmother(clara,jose). -- yes
  ```
- ¿es pedro abuelo de clara ?

  ```
  ? - grandfather(pedro,clara). -- yes
  ```

Por lo que el código final sería:

```
female(clara).
female(ana).
male(pedro).
male(jose).
parent(clara, pedro).
parent(pedro, jose).
parent(ana, clara).
parent(jose, clara).
mother(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y), female(X).
mother(clara, pedro).
mother(ana, clara).
father(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y), male(X).
father(pedro, jose).
father(jose, clara).
grandmother(X,Y) :- parent(X,Z), parent(Z,Y), female(X).
grandfather(X,Y) :- parent(X,Z), parent(Z,Y), male(X).

? - grandmother(clara,jose).
? - grandfather(pedro,clara).
```

Dónde AMBOS son `true` ya que hay un ciclo en la definición.

> Ana
>
> Clara
>
> Pedro
>
> Jose (que también es padre de Clara)